# copy only some strings from a BST into another BST

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, copy-paste

i have a problem copying the strings contained in a BST into another BST: my aim is to copy from the original BST only the nodes with the flag `usable`. the problem is that after i run the function to copy those nodes the resulting BST is empty. any suggestions?

```
 struct node {
    char *value;
    struct node *p_left;
    struct node *p_right;
    int usable;
};

void copiaAlbero(struct node *root, struct node *alberino)
{
    if( root != NULL ) {
        copiaAlbero(root->p_left,alberino);
        if (root->usable==1)
            inserisciInAlbero(root->value, &alberino, (Compare) CmpStr);
        copiaAlbero(root->p_right, alberino);
    }
}

void inserisciInAlbero(char* key, struct node** leaf, Compare cmp) {
    int res;
    if( *leaf == NULL ) {
        *leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        (*leaf)->value = malloc( strlen (key) +1 );
        strcpy ((*leaf)->value, key);
        (*leaf)->usable=1;
        (*leaf)->p_left = NULL;
        (*leaf)->p_right = NULL;
    } else {
        res = cmp (key, (*leaf)->value);
        if( res < 0)
            inserisciInAlbero( key, &(*leaf)->p_left, cmp);
        else if( res > 0)
            inserisciInAlbero( key, &(*leaf)->p_right, cmp);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *alberino = NULL;
    //head gets filled and other operations assign 1 or 0 to usable
    copiaAlbero(head, alberino);
}
```

at the end of this code i should have all the strings of head marked with usable contained into alberino, but alberino is now empty.

Comment: You've omitted a lot of code.  Are you populating `head` correctly?  How do you know?  More importantly, how can we know?

Comment: It seems you ought to get a compiler warning that you are passing the wrong type for the second parameter of `inserisciInAlbero`.  It expects a `struct node**`, but you are passing a `struct node*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just look at the lines:

```
struct node *alberino = NULL;
copiaAlbero(head, alberino);
```

you know that `alberino == NULL` after the call to `copiaAlbero`.  If you want to modify `alberino`, you must change that to `copiaAlbero(head, &alberino)` and of course make all the necessary changes to accommodate that.

Comment: so i should change the call to `copiaAlbero(head, &alberino)` and the function copiaAlbero to `void copiAlbero(struct node *root, struct node **alberino)
{
    if( root != NULL ) {
        copiaAlbero(root->p_left,alberino);
        if (root->usable==1)
            inserisciInAlbero(root->value, &alberino, (Compare) CmpStr);
        copiaAlbero(root->p_right, alberino);
    }
}`?

Comment: Not quite.  Change the parameter of `copiaAlbero`, but call `inserisciInAlbero(root->value, alberino, ....)`. At that point, `alberino` is the correct type.

Comment: in other parts of the code, where i call `inserisciInAlbero` i call it like this `inserisciInAlbero(parola, &head, (Compare) CmpStr);` and works fine... sorry but i'm a bit of dummy and i don't understand too well..

Comment: If `head` is of type `struct node *`, then you need to use the address-of operator to get a `struct node **`.  Since you use the address-of operator in `main` (in the modified version) to get the address of `alberino`, you already have a `struct node **`.  It might help to understand if you change the name and do something like `void copiaAlbero(struct node *root, struct node ** ptr_to_alberino)`. (Or just call it `bst` or `dest` or `node` or `tree`.  Reusing the name `alberino` is just going to cause confusion)

Comment: i modified as such and seems to work, thank you so much! `void copiaAlbero(struct node *origin, struct node** dest)
{
    if(origin != NULL ) {
        copiaAlbero(origin->p_left, dest);
        if (origin->usable == 1)
            inserisciInAlbero(origin->value, dest, (Compare) CmpStr);
        copiaAlbero(origin->p_right, dest);
    }
}`